# Can i modify a GPL v3 project and distribute it under GPL v3 license with my name?

Tags: gpl, gpl-3

Hello i was making a c plus plus program and the **program uses some files of a project licensed under GNU GPL Version 3.0**

When the program( i created) completes and i license it under GPL v3.

Below is an excerpt from the license of Pawn Programming Language

```
The software toolkit "Pawn" (the compiler, the abstract machine and the support
routines) is copyright (c) 1997-2017 by ITB CompuPhase, and distributed under
the "Apache License" version 2.0, which is reproduced below, plus an exception
clause regarding static linking.
```

So like that my license should start like

```
The software (My Software Name) is copyright (c) 2022 by **My Name**, and distributed under the "GNU GPL License" version 3.0, which is found in file COPYING.txt.
```

So my question is in the above paragraph should i use My Name or "The Original Author of the some files which i have made use in my Project.

In individual files of the program, i learned that i have to put

```
/*
    Copyright (c) 2022 My Name
    Copyright (c) 2004-2005 Original Author
    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.
    
    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.
    
    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
*/
    class CGamemode
    {
    private:
    //
    public:
    void GameInit();
    ...
    }
```

So i repeat my question which is as the whole project can it be first licensed under my name with GPL v3 and subsequently show that it uses parts of Project created by Author licensed under GPL v3.

Edit 9. Feb 2022
The excerpt from Pawn programming language is shown as license file which the Pawn program uses. Pawn is licensed under Apache 2.0 that i know. Infact, i use Pawn source files in my project. I also make use of a project SA-MP, which is a multiplayer modification of game. This SA-MP is licensed under GPL v3. As that is so, my whole program can be licensed under GPL v3. The question is under whose name.-My name or SA-MP team. Can i license it under my name and give credits.

Comment: "distributed under the "Apache License" version 2.0" While it doesn't actually make very much difference, this code is blatantly not distributed under the GPL.

Comment: Sorry, i had not made it clear in my question that i use code from multiple projects. I have now edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that the question revolves around a misunderstanding: that a piece of software is "licensed under somebody's name".  It isn't, so the issue of whether you can "*licence this work under your own name*" is a non-question.

You have created a work that incorporates parts from many other works, distributed to you under a variety of free licences (in your case, Apache2 and GPLv3).  This is a perfectly normal thing to do in the free-software world, so don't panic.  Each of those licences will have certain obligations, **all** of which you must now follow with respect to your derivative work.

As you have observed, you will need to preserve all existing copyright notices.  In files that you have modified, you will need to add your own copyright notice to the existing list.  If the pre-existing Apache2 code includes a `NOTICE` file, [Apache2](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0) s4d obliges you to preserve (parts of) it, and best-practice would suggest that you add yourself to any list of rightsholders therein.  As you have used GPLv3 code, your project must be distributed in its entirety under GPLv3; if the Apache2-derived code contains any references to its licence status, these should be updated to reflect that.

Comment: @HabiHaris you're welcome, and I'm glad you found what I wrote to be helpful.