# Using code licensed under an MIT license with code licensed under the GPL

Tags: licensing, gpl, mit, gpl-3, license-compatibility

Say I have a repository that uses the GPL and I want to include code from a repository under the MIT license. I found [here](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#WhatDoesCompatMean) that MIT and GPL licensed code can be freely combined; however, I am unsure about the exact way to go about this. Does this mean that I have to include the MIT license somewhere in my repo, and if so, where would I put it? Can I just include the code without worry since my repo is under the GPL?

Comment: Could you take a look at [this answer](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/12650/458), which is about mixing permissively-licensed content with GPL content, and say if it answers your question in principle?  I accept the specifics of the MIT licence are slightly different, but the guiding principles are the same.